# How to vectorize pandas operation to improve speed?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, bigdata, vectorization

This is a SKU affinity problem. I have a dataframe like this. Each ctn_id has multiple sku_codes.

[image]

```
dfr = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ctn_id','sku_code'])
dfr['ctn_id'] = np.random.randint(low=1,high=21,size=200)
dfr['sku_code'] = np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d'],size=200)
dfr.drop_duplicates(['ctn_id','sku_code'], inplace=True)
```

I want to fill the following dataframe.

[image]

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sku_code','a','b','c','d'])
dfx['sku_code'] = ['a','b','c','d']
dfx = dfx.fillna(0)
dfx.set_index('sku_code',inplace=True)
```

using the logic below

```
for idx in dfr['ctn_id'].unique():
    x = list(dfr[dfr['ctn_id'] == idx]['sku_code'].unique())
    for skui in dfx.index:
        if skui in x:
            for skuj in x:
                dfx.loc[skui, skuj] = dfx.loc[skui, skuj] + 1
```

I have 2.5M ctn_ids and 400 sk_codes, making it a total of billion assignment operations. Is there a better way to do this using pandas or any other package?

Comment: How much memory does your machine have?

Comment: 16GB. The dfr dataframe would be around 600MB though.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Comment: you can run the last snippet of code to get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ctn_id` having `integers,` we can use an **array-assignment** based method to get all the mappings on a `2D` grid and then use matrix-multiplication to get *binned-summations*, similar to shown in [`@scomes's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55839019/) -

```
Ie = dfr.ctn_id.values
J = dfr.sku_code.values

I = pd.factorize(Ie,sort=False)[0]
col2IDs,col2L = pd.factorize(J,sort=True) #use sort=False if order is irrelevant
a = np.zeros((I.max()+1,col2IDs.max()+1),dtype=int)
a[I,col2IDs] = 1
df_out = pd.DataFrame(a.T.dot(a), columns=col2L, index=col2L)
```

**Alternative #1**

For a better performance, we can use `float` values for matrix-multiplication. For that, use `float` dtype to get `a`. Hence, setup `a`, like so -

```
a = np.zeros((I.max()+1,col2IDs.max()+1),dtype=float)
```

**Alternative #2**

Or use a boolean array to store `1s` and then convert dtype :

```
a = np.zeros((I.max()+1,col2IDs.max()+1),dtype=bool)
a[I,col2IDs] = 1
a = a.astype(float)
```

Comment: It works!. I will accept the answer which gives better performance on real data.

Comment: I am getting `MemoryError:` on real data.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated to handle duplicates from random input**

This answer assumes there are no duplicate rows (rows with the same ctn_id and sku_code). You can easily extend this answer for that use case though.

Yes, you can pivot the data frame so that the ctn_ids are the rows and the sku_codes are the columns. To do this, you can add a dummy column that is all 1s, then use

```
dfr['Dummy'] = 1
piv = dfr.drop_duplicates().pivot('ctn_id', 'sku_code', 'Dummy').fillna(0.0)
```

Now you have essentially a sparse matrix with a 1 wherever there is a ctn_id/sku_code relationship and a 0 otherwise. From here you can just use matrix algebra.

```
mat = piv.values
counts = mat.T.dot(mat)
```

The variable `counts` has what you are looking for (it will be symmetric and values will be the number of times the sku_codes are seen together in a ctn_id, which is what I believe you are looking for.

Comment: see the note about assuming no duplicates. the random numbers may make duplicates. I am assuming the target input is not random...

Comment: In the real problem, there won't be duplicates. Anyways, I edited my code in the question to remove duplicates

Comment: I will spend some time to understand but it works!. Not sure how much time it will take for real data set.

Comment: @Vinay That last line is just multiplying a matrix by its transpose. In this case, since the matrix is 1s and 0s, its giving a count of the number of times 2 sku_codes appear in the same ctn_id.

Comment: Got it. But it's blowing up my memory. I will try @user3483203's answer, which he deleted now(luckily I saved it) but claims will address the memory issue.

Comment: @Vinay yeah, this one will create a 2.5m X 400 matrix in your case. Their answer appears to be more memory efficient.

Comment: your answer is the only one which is working on real data. My memory was full but it completed in 4min.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will give it a shot.

Not sure if this is going to be *fast enough* but I'd say it is already way faster than your chained for loops.

It uses a *hacky* way to perform *"vectorized"* set difference.

```
s = df.groupby(['sku_code']).ctn_id.agg(set)
pd.DataFrame(map(lambda s: list(map(len,s)), np.array(s) & np.array(s).reshape([-1,1])))

    0   1   2   3
0   18  17  18  16
1   17  19  19  17
2   18  19  20  17
3   16  17  17  17
```

With the sample you provided, there is a ~100x performance gain.

```
# your method
79.4 ms ± 3.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# my try
668 µs ± 30.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Tried your solution. But getting an error `data argument can't be an iterator`

Comment: @vinay just wrap the maps with lists